# iphone memory management: alloc and retain properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

According to the docs, you do one release per alloc or retain (etc)
However what about when using retain propertys?

eg:

```
HEADER
@property(retain)UIView *someView;

IMPLEMENTATION
/*in some method*/
UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] init]; //<<<<<ALLOC - retain count = +1
[tempView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
self.someView = tempView; ///<<<<<RETAIN - retain count = +2
[tempView release];   ///should I do this?
```

or a different version of the IMPLEMENTATION

```
self.someView = [[UIView alloc] init]; //<<<<<ALLOC & RETAIN - retain count = +2
//now what??? [self.someView release]; ????
```

EDIT: I didn't make it clear, but I meant what to do in both circumstances, not just the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/*in some method*/
UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] init]; //<<<<<ALLOC - retain count = +1
[tempView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
self.someView = tempView; ///<<<<<RETAIN - retain count = +2
[tempView release];   ///should I do this? // YES!!!!
```

And you should also release all retain properties in your dealloc method, before [super dealloc].

Answer (score 0):

Your first version is correct. There's only one ongoing reference to the view, so a retain count of 1 is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

For the second sample, you can use `autorelease`:

```
self.someView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: `autorelease` should be used very sparingly.  Because the autorelease pool is managed by the runtime, you lose control of when objects are reclaimed when the autorelease pool is freed.  I would use `autorelease` almost always when returning objects from a method, and even then, only when not frequently used.